How to parse large JSON Strings(>5,000,000) using Play JSON?
I'm using Play JSON 2.9.4 in Scala.
implementation group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-json_2.12', version: '2.9.4
I'm unable to parse JSON Strings larger than 5,000,000 characters.
The exception thrown is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.StreamConstraintsException: String length (5043368) exceeds the maximum length (5000000)
I can see that it is occurring due to: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/1001
How can I configure this limit through Play-JSON or in any way, I can't find any way to do this ?

Usually the answer that I saw when it comes to JSON and size issues was: use another library. Jsoniter Scala was what I usually heard when someone had to handle large JSONs.

Thanks for the library suggestion @MateuszKubuszok . Shifting to a different library would require changes in multiple places. It will be done ultimately, but I need a quick fix rn.

I think you could use PlayJsonModule. The description says "...This can be used if you want to use a custom Jackson ObjectMapper...", which lets you access to ObjectMapper. As it is suggested in the mentioned issue, from there you could do objectMapper.getFactory().setStreamReadConstraints(StreamReadConstraints.builder().maxStringLength(10_000_000).build()). PlayJsonModule was deprecated in play 2.9, but you can use PlayJsonMapperModule

Thanks for the pointer @GastónSchabas, I'll have to read this large string in multiple places. Any way to set this globally. The codebase contains a ton of Json.parse already

I don't think there is a way where you can change something and that will solve the problem. If you are calling Json.parsedirectly in different places, you will need to go to each place and change it. You can define a helper function like MyJsonHelper.parse(string): JsValue to centralize it. If you need a different configuration for each value you need to parse the solution will be different

What I don't exactly understand if your problem is in the request or is inside the service. For the requests, maybe changing the max content length limit would be enough. If you need something more specific, a custom body parser must be created

If None of what I detailed before is enough to solve your issue, please provide some code that shows what you are facing. A minimal reproducible example if it is possible
